# Python showing completely incorrect results in 85% of the cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code which takes a while to run.
I've added a simple status message to let me know if it is still running and where it is standing - see below code

```
n=1000
tlast = perf_counter()
for i in range(n):
    #... lots of stuff here
    if perf_counter() - tlast > 10:
        tlast = perf_counter()
        print("Still working {:2.1f}%".format(i/n*100))
```

It does what is should, except: instead of the actual status in % it randomly shows another number (which seems to be related to n - my number of cycles). see below:

```
Still working 2.0%
Still working 2.0%
Still working 39.8%
Still working 2.0%
Still working 2.0%
Still working 2.0%
Still working 2.0%
```

The proportion of incorrect statuses can be as high as 85%, and now I am wondering if it is "just a display issue", or the accuracy of calculations are so unreliable??
I've tried different formatting methods without success, and also googled around, but most hits lead to the inaccuracy of floats - and that does not seem to be the issue here...
Does anybody know what causes it, and what can be done to eliminate it?
Tx

Comment: have you tried `(i/n)*100` ?

Comment: Is it related to the fact that `347/1000 = 0` (integer division)?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? The meaning of `/` changed between 2 and 3

Comment: yes, I've tried brackets, same result, and it should not be the issue - i think...
also 347/1000 shows correctly 0.347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause, it was a mistake in the code
(the variable i was reused inside an if statement within the code: when the if statement activated, it gave a new value to i, in other cases it did not)
sorry for wasting your time and thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `i` and also `n` are integers:

```
float(i)/n*100
```

Comment: no, sorry, that is not it...

Comment: 1. The OP is using Python 3, and 2. If this were the problem, it would manifest itself as a bunch of `0` results, which is not happening.

Comment: I didnt know that in python3 they changed type conversion.

Comment: @Andrew Even then, 2.7 wouldn't give the results we're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working in Python 3.4.0.

```
if time.perf_counter() - tlast > 10:
    tlast = time.perf_counter()
    print("Still working: {0:.2f}".format(100/n*i) + "%")
```